# SQL Server 2008 Full text Search Performance Issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I recently upgraded from a Win 2003 / SQL Server 2000 (HP ML350 G4p - Dual Xeon with 2GB RAM) to new hardware (IBM x3200 M3 - Single Xeon QC X3450 2.66GHz 10GB RAM) running Win 2008 R2 / SQL Server 2008. We run a classic ASP website and use Full Text Search to enable customers to search our product descriptions.

The search is performed by a stored procedure which builds up a dynamic query to run the search using the `contains` predicate.

I have an intermittent problem in that some searches are extremely slow. Sometimes taking over a minute to complete. At other times they will complete in less than a second. Didn't have this problem on the old server at all.

I have replicated this problem by running the stored procedure from the SSMS, and again, this can sometimes take an extremely long time.

I suspect the new Full Text Search system within SQL Server 2008, but I'm not sure how to pinpoint the issue. When the timeouts are occurring, there doesn't seem to be a big load on the server cpu.  I don't know where else to look. Relatively new to SQL Server 2008.

Change Tracking on the Index if set to Off, and I'm running a job to incrementally update the index each day, as well as optimizing the catalog each day.

Searching around on Google, this seems to be reasonably common a problem, but I haven't found a definitive answer to it yet.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in Advance,
Mike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone else has this issue, I've finally solved it. I needed to apply Cumulative Update 9 then do the following: –

DBCC TRACEON(4199, -1);
GO;

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
GO;

Found the answer from a post by Forrestsjs on this page:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsearch/thread/7e45b7e4-2061-4c89-af68-febd668f346c/

Responses have dropped from about 3 minutes to 2-3 seconds for wildcard searches such as: "office 2010 pro*"

Comment: Spent 3 days before found your solution. Now it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just found this: [StackOverflow’s SQL 2008 FTS issue solved](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/11/stackoverflows-sql-2008-fts-issue-solved/) (what service pack and/or cumulative updates have you applied?)

Did you rebuild **ALL** indexes after upgrading from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008?

You need to.

Run this (but make sure you have your DBA/Manager/whoever's permission before running in production):

```
exec sp_msforeachtable "DBCC DBREINDEX('?')"
go

exec sp_msforeachtable "UPDATE STATISTICS ? WITH FULLSCAN, COLUMNS"
go
```

Also, Update usage counters: In earlier versions of SQL Server, the values for the table and index row counts and page counts can become incorrect. To correct any invalid row or page counts, run **`DBCC UPDATEUSAGE`** on all databases following the upgrade.

If that doesn't fix your problem, investigate setting 'Max Degree of Parallelism' to 1.

This post might be helpful: [Upgrading from SQL Server 2000 to 2008](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com.au/2010/10/upgrading-from-sql-server-2000-to-2008.html)

The behaviour you describe "Sometimes taking over a minute to complete. At other times they will complete in less than a second" is usually a sign that inappropriate query plans are being cached.

Have you read this?: [SQL 2008 Full-Text Search Problems](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/sql-2008-full-text-search-problems/)

Do you have a large number of updates occurring?

From this post [SQL Server 2008 Full Text slowness](http://barry-king.com/2008/09/16/sql-server-2008-full-text-slowness/) :

> It appears to happen if:
>
> - You have AUTO tracking on your full text indexes; although we changed    it to manual and still had this issue.
> - You experience Full-text    queries taking a long time to execute; normally when updates are    happening at the same time so you might
>   only see this in production.
> - One or more of your queries are complicated or take some time to complete.
>
> You can check to see if your system is slow due to this
> by:
>
> - SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats statement , it shows very high wait times some of the locks.
> - Running Sp_who2; it should consistently show that the full-text gather is blocking full-text queries and, in turn, is being blocked by
>   the queries.
>
> The current work around for this issue is to use a global trace flag
> microsoft kindly enabled on the RTM build.  To use this, type the
> following Transact-SQL statement:   **DBCC TRACEON (7646, -1)**

Comment: Thanks Mitch.  I'll have a read of your linked posts and will see what happens.  Appreciate you time to reply. You've given me a lot to satrt on.  Cheers - Mike.

Comment: Hi again Mitch.  SP3 has been applied to the database as far as I can tell. DB version is 10.0.5500.

You mention I need to rebuild ALL indexes.  I've found info on how to do this for a single table via the SSMS, but is there a command I can run to do it on all tables?

Cheers - Mike.

Comment: Hi.

Performance seems to be a lot better after rebuilding indexes, but still not ideal.  I'm wondering if the issue may be with the query plans.  Eg If I perform a 2 token search such as "Samsung SSD" it will take around 9 seconds to perform the search initially, but after that  subsequent searches for the likes of "Samsung 13.3" or "Samsung SSD" are almost instantaneous.  Is the fact I'm using build a Dynamic Query in my SP a factor?  If I change from a Dynamic query to a bunch of separate static queries, do you think the query plan caching would improve?
Thanks,
Mike.

Comment: Dynamic queries usually suffer less from inappropriate plan caching. You could try adding the option to compile the query each time.

Comment: Hi Mitch, Testing today using the wilcard character resulted in a timeout error. I use the Contains predicate, not Freetext. Search was done on "8GB SD*". Does the new search engine not like wilcards like this? – Cheers - Mike.

Comment: I just wanted to comment on this. I am running SQL 2008 SP3 (not R2). I am seeing this exact issue. I tried all of the above to try and fix it to no avail. What I didn't try was the Trace flag as assumed that the "bug" or "workaround" would be solved by SP3. However, I finally gave in and added the trace flag and all the issues went away. Does this mean that this is something that is not yet fixed? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: I used the trace flag after reading your post Robin, but it hasn't solved my issue.